# Yii Url Manager Issue

Tags: php, yii, url-rewriting

I'm using Yii URL manager to rewrite urls of the type /events/?event=my%20event to
/events/my%20event

The code below works, but for some reason, it only works if there is a space. So

events/my event, and events/my-event, and event/my&20event

all works, but

events/test or events/newEvent

do not

```
'urlManager'=>array(
        'urlFormat'=>'path',
        'showScriptName'=>false,
        'rules'=>array(
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
    'events/<event>' => 'events/index',
        ),
    ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put last rule 'events/' => 'events/index', on the first place of array

```
'urlManager'=>array(
    'urlFormat'=>'path',
    'showScriptName'=>false,
    'rules'=>array(
        'events/<event>' => 'events/index',
        '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
    ),
),
```